# Is there a 'User manual' for Android 2.1?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, documentation

The user guides that came with my Android 2.1 phone are pretty basic and mostly geared to the mobile company's interface and apps. I've come across [this PDF guide to Android 2.2](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//googlephone/AndroidUsersGuide.pdf). Is there something similar for 2.1?

Update:
Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) user manual now available [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//googlephone/AndroidUsersGuide-2.3.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Nexus One user manual](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/googlephone/nexusone-userguide.pdf) seems to be basically the same document as you linked, but specific to that phone and Android 2.1. Since the Nexus One was a "pure" Android experience, the vast majority of the document should cover what you're looking for.

(That link seems dead, but [this link from the Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20100212125555/http://www.google.com/googlephone/nexusone-userguide.pdf) seems to be working. There's also [this link from T-Mobile](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-1938).)

Comment: Yep, seems to be the same Google produced document with added Nexus One specifics. I wonder if Google post these anywhere public as they're updated for new Android versions.

Comment: became 404 in 2012

Comment: @naxa: I added a link to the Wayback machine.